# Does anyone have samples of pentest contracts?

Tags: penetration-test

I'm a newbie to actual contracts for doing penetration tests, but I hear they are an absolute must.  Does anyone have any samples of contracts for the "get out of jail card" language in there?  I'm willing to do reconnaissance without one, but if I have been asked to exploit vulnerabilities on purpose I think I should protect myself.

Comment: I think nobody is going to share any contract. It always have confidential information that mustn't be disclosed.

Comment: This is more of a legal than an information security topic. Also, the jurisdiction you're operating in would obviously matter (which you didn't disclose).

Comment: OWASP have this: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authorization_form

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis not a *completed* contract, the OP is looking for sample ones ...

Comment: there are a lot out there with the search "pen test contract" - including the duplicate

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction.  I didn't realize it was a duplicate.